# Google Colab notebook preview (thumbnail) not updating in Drive

Tags: google-colaboratory

There used to be an option in Google Colab under `File` called `Update Drive preview`. I no longer see that option and my previews are very out of date. I assumed if it was removed that maybe the preview was updated when saving, but that does not appear to be the case. The worst part is that I have renamed the files and the preview still shows the old filename along the top, which can be confusing. Is another way that I can make this update occur?

[image]

**Edit:**
It is important to note that I do not want the URL for sharing to change, so making a copy would not work as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Update Drive preview` is now available through the command palette in Colab which is available through `Tools->command palette`, `[CMD/CTRL]+SHIFT+P`, or in the menu along the left side of the notebook.